# Parsing arrays in logic apps

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I have a JSON schema that looks like this:

```
InputParameters": [
{
  "key": "Target",
  "value": {
    "__type": "Entity:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
    "Attributes": [
      {
        "key": "prioritycode",
        "value": {
          "__type": "OptionSetValue:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
          "Value": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "completeinternalreview",
        "value": false
      },
      {
        "key": "stepname",
        "value": "1-Lead"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

This is from a CRM message that gets read off a queue.

What is the best way to read the key value pairs? Seems like there is no way to do nested for loops if you have nested arrays.

Can I use function apps with JSON.NET to do some funky stuff instead?

Comment: Nested for-each will be available very soon, in the mean time you can pass the item to a child logic app and loop over attributes inside each item in the child logic app.